# Trouble with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
match = Regex.Match(theString, @"\W|_").NextMatch();
```

What exactly does this line do? I've read that the \W should match any non-alphanumeric character - which is exactly what i'm looking for. I want to be able to could the number of characters in a string which are not numeric and which are not letters. So for instance, the string "!>*t!%@^" should return 6, since "t" is a letter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try running that line on a list of possible input strings?

Comment: @sq33g yes, i did, but it fails each time because it returns 7 instead of 6. I don't want to account for letters or numbers. I want to count every other character though

Comment: @aleph_null no, i don't want to get 7 as a result, i want to get 6 as a result as i DON'T want to count the letter "t". I want everything excluding letters and numbers

Comment: @BlueMonster 7 is correct, without the "t" based on your example string, which is *eight* characters in length. `!` (1), `>` (2), `*` (3), `!` (4), `%` (5), `@` (6), `^` (7). Did you mean *unique* characters?

Comment: @BlueMonster everyone's code so far returns 7, which is correct. If you want 6 then I suspect you want to count unique characters, which would make the exclamation point count once instead of twice.

Comment: Ok, i see, i was using the code by FailedDev and that returned 7. The code i posted returns 8. In each case i tested my code, it returns the entire string, rather than excluding portions of it. I guess i'll use FailedDev's solution. Although, i'm still wondering why mine fails.. Thanks vcsjones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is an overkill for this in my opinion :

```
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var c in subjectString)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", count);
```

That 'll have the same result.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for a regular expression to count non-alphanumeric characters. Try this instead:

```
int count = ((IEnumerable<char>)s).Count(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
```

Comment: @MarkByers +1 Wrote same thing differently :)

Comment: @Mark Byers Hmm.... I tried this but it says that "String" does not contain a definition for Count? Not sure how Count works, could you explain a bit further?

Comment: @BlueMonster That's LINQ. Requires C# 3.0 and you should have a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your source file.

Comment: @vcsjones Thanks...hm, i can't seem to use Linq though, i also don't see a reference to add either under References in order to use it..

Comment: @BlueMonster: When you create a new file in Visual Studio the `using System.Linq;` statement should already be there. Maybe you are using a very old version of C#? If so, you should really mention it in your question as it will affect the answers.

Comment: @Mark Byers Hmm yes, u're right, it should be. I'm testing someone else's code. the using System.Linq is not present in the file which i'm testing (which i didn't create) but it is present in the file i created for testing purposes. I can't seem to add it in the file that i'm testing.. for some reason....? Not sure why..

Answer (score 1):

You're right that your regex should match what you want (assuming you can ignore other characters from the Punctuation, Connector category).

To get the count of matches, you can do something like this:

```
Regex.Matches(theString, @"\W|_").Count
```

Answer (score 0):

That line /should/ match any single non-word character. However, I believe you're only matching one of them. You'll need to either put that in a while loop and add a counter, or find out how your language can match a regex "globally". Look into the Matches method, which will allow you to do that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx

Comment: Hmm yea, in my code, i have it within a for loop in order to get the next one... but... it fails the test i have set up. So just wondering why it's failing